# Why here string literal are not interned?

Tags: java, string

Here is my main class

```
public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String args[])  {
   String str1 = "testString";
        String str2 = "testString" + 1; //line1
        //above  literal value(i.e str2 = "testString1") is interned and stored in permamnent generation space
        //now when whenever i create "testString1" down the line in this program, it should refer from same location
        //but it does not seem true
        TestThread tt= new TestThread(str1, str2);
        tt.start();

        }

}
```

Here is my thread class

```
package Test;

public class TestThread extends Thread {
    String str2;

public TestThread( String str3, String str4) {
        this.str3 = str3 + 1; //line2
        System.out.println("value inside Thread is "+this.str3);
        System.out.println("value inside Thread is "+str4);
        if(str3 == str4){
            System.out.println("Yes they are equal");
        }else{
        System.out.println("They are not equal");
        }

        //line 3


    @Override
    public void run(){
       // some processing           
        }
}
```

At line 3, "They are not equal" is printed. But why ? line 2 should refer same string as at line 1 as i am using string literal which
  are interned and stored in permgen space.

**Update :-** Is there a way i can force compiler to use string literal instead of optimizing the code to use new String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.str3 = str3 + 1; //line2
```

You are using concatenation at runtime which always creates a new String which is not interned by default. You can use  `intern()` method on this and then try to compare.

```
String str2 = "testString" + 1; //line1
```

This is a `compile time constant expression` and on successful compilation will be converted to

```
String str2 = "testString1";
```

which is a String literal and will be interned. Now in your run method you are creating a new String as I explained previously. Hence both are pointing to different String instances and hence `==` will give you false.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method of the String class to get desired result, here is a working example of your TestThread:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {
  String str3;

  public TestThread( String str3, String str4) {
    this.str3 = str3 + 1; //line2
    System.out.println("value inside Thread is "+this.str3);
    System.out.println("value inside Thread is "+str4);
    if(this.str3.intern() == str4.intern()){
      System.out.println("Yes they are equal");
    }else{
      System.out.println("They are not equal");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    // some processing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at decompiled code,  you should see below code at line 2 as compiler try to optimize the code

```
  this.str3 = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(str3))).append(1).toString();
```

So at last its creating new String object with new operator  while toString()

Comment: Is there a way i can force compiler to use string literal instead of optimizing the code to use new String ?

Comment: No. There's no string literal in line 3 that could be used.